# Continuous probability - calculate probability of r.v and distribution function

Tags: probability

This is the question:

> $X$ is a continuous random variable whose probability density function
>   is given by
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
>      \frac{1}{9}x^2 & \text{if $0\leq x \leq 3$}.\\
>      0 & \text{otherwise}.   \end{cases}$$
>
> (a) what is the probability that $X$ is less than $1$?
>   (b) Write down the distribution function $F_{X}(x)$ for $X$ (remember to
>   include the values for $F_{X}$ for all real $x$).

So for (a), I am looking for 
$P\{X < 1\} = \frac{1}{9}\int_{-\infty}^{1}x^2\,dx$
however how do I compute the definite integral with negative infinity? Am I allowed to replace the negative infinity with $0$ since the function ranges from $0$ to $3$?

For (b), I am not sure how do this exactly, well my book says "derive and then differentiate the distribution function".

Comment: $f(x)=0$ for $x \lt 0$

Comment: It is a poor choice of words.  They should say "obtain and partition" the distribution function (since its a piece-wise function).

Answer (score 3):

a. Yes, since the density is not zero over $[0,3]$, then
$$P(X\leq 1) = \int_0^1 f_X(x)\,dx.$$

b. In this case, it is asking to find the cdf
$$P(X\leq x).$$
By

> Remember to include the values for $F_X$ for all real $x$

I believe it is saying to make sure you are explicit about the cases
$$P(X\leq x)$$
when

1. $x< 0 $
2. $0\leq x \leq 3$, and
3. $x>3$.

In other words, your answer should look like
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases}
\_\_\_\_,&\text{if } x<0\\
\_\_\_\_,&\text{if } 0\leq x\leq 3\\
\_\_\_\_,&\text{if } x>3.
\end{cases}$$